# Vba Excel programing

Tags: excel, userform

I have created my Userform in excel

drafting it in the excel sheets and recording using the record macro button

using CTRL C and CTRL V FROM THE Sheets

I have added a macro button also

When I tested the user form, its works with 1st data (investor data)

when I wanted to fill the 2nd investor, the data was replaced in the same row every time It goes to the same row.

What I Should do?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Hi reda. Unfortunately there's no way for us to understand your problem and help you if you don't post any code. Please edit your question to include some code, and what you've done to try to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Hello, thank you for your kind reply, Please allow me to clarify the idea, I have created my user form using the drafting in the excel sheet and recording the method not using the VBA insert method

Comment: Hi Reda. I think your problem is that the macro you have recorded is always acting on the same row when you want it to change what row it acts on based on some criteria. This is a common problem when recording macros, you are going to have to edit the code.
Please open the code and click F8 to go through it step-by-step, then edit your question to show the code and which line is not doing what you want it to.

Comment: The macro recorder is frankly almost worthless for creating any general-purpose VBA macro. If you haven't done so already, I would recommend spending some time working through a book or tutorial on full-fledged VBA programming. The macro recorder is still useful -- but you almost always need to substantially edit and add to the code that it produces.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.